# changing mesh name

Tags: outliner

when I export file from blender, I could not export the mesh with renamed data.
It was as the same as the name it just duplicated.
I could not repeat that problem in new scene but I wish if there are way to make sure to clear whole possiblity to inherite old name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, not the viewer stored something about the topology? Did you try to import it to an other software or back to Blender?

Comment: yes   .glb sometimes become so.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. There is a menu: File>>Clean Up to clear unused data I hope it will help.

Comment: thank you very much FFeller.    Clean up also seems work other times.  This time I selected the object data in outliner and right click>Unlink  and then ctrl+Z(undo) then somehow I could export renamed data.

Comment: maybe only my version 2.93.5 and when I export glb file.